# Algebra Puzzle Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Julia drives to her holiday destination over a period of five days. On the first day she travels a certain distance, on the second day she travels half that distance, on the third day a third of that distance, on the fourth day one quarter of the distance and on the fifth day one fifth of the distance. If her destination is $1000$ km away, write an equation and solve it to find how far she travels on the first day to the nearest kilometre.

A textbook question from my exercise. The textbook solution is $438$ km.

**My attempt**

Let distance travelled on the first day $= x$

Then

$x+x/2+x/6+x/24+x/120=1000$

$(103/60)x=1000$

$x=583$

Therefore distance travelled on the first day is $583$ km.

Is the mistake in my working or is the textbook solution provided incorrect?

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: I dont understand ?

Comment: I suppose, from my first impression, **that distance** is always referring to the distance made on the first day

Comment: The "distance" is always the one of the first day (not the distance of the previous day). Therefore the equation should be $x+x/2+x/3+x/4+x/5=1000$

Comment: So where is the error in my working?

Comment: You have a different equation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x+x/2+x/3+x/4+x/5=1000$$

$$x=437.95$$

I think now you will understand where you mistaken.

Hope it will help you.

Nice attempt.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

There is an ambiguity in the question when it talks about *that* distance in. e.g. "on the third day a third of that distance" ... is 'that distance' referring to the distance of the previous day, or is the phrase always referring to the distance of the very first day? You interpreted the phrase in the former way, but the book interpreted it in the latter way.